# When certain button pressed change the motion of the prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First when I start the program the prefab should start with the `round()` method. Now when I press m the prefab should have the motion `random()` . When I press agian m it should go back to the method `round()`.

My code didn't work. When I press m the `random()` is running only for a second.

```
...
    bool mode = false;
    ....

         void Update()
            {

                round();
                if (Input.GetKeyDown("m") && mode == true) {
                    round();
                    mode = false;
                }else if (Input.GetKeyDown("m") && mode == false)
                {
                    random();
                    mode = true;
                } 
            }
...
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

First you call `round();` every update, than you call `random()` every other frame while you are holding the m key.

Try

```
bool allowModeChange=true;
...
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("m"))
    {
        if (allowModeChange)
        {
            mode = !mode;
            allowModeChange = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        allowModeChange = true;
    }
    if (mode)
    {
        random();
    } 
    else 
    {
        round();
    }
}
```

`allowModeChange` prevents you to flip mode every frame while holding the m key.